# Angular2 ngModelChange previous value

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

Is there a way to get the previous(last) value of a field on ngModelChange?
What I have goes something like this

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)">
```

Handler

```
private textChanged(event) {
    console.log('changed', this.text, event);
}
```

What I get is

```
changed *newvalue* *newvalue*
```

Of course I can keep the older value using another variable, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So found kinda weird(at least for me) possible solution for this with least changes in the code in question. So on assigning the `(ngModelChange)` attribute before `[(ngModel)]` what I get is following with the same handler:

```
changed *older value* *new value*
```

I get the new value in `this.text`like so:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log(this.text), 0);
```

Comment: This little caveat was costing me time, wasn't aware that the order of ngModel and ngModelChange made a difference.

Comment: Oh, that __is__ awkward! Why should the order make a difference?

Comment: one of the dumb things about Angular is that it seems these little nuances are more frequent than not. What a dumb feature, but thank you for finding this!

Comment: Wow... Awesome find! This alongside Micronyks' answer would collectively be THE answer.

Comment: Wow! This is weird

Answer (score 44):

What you can do is,

DEMO : http://plnkr.co/edit/RXJ4D0YJrgebzYcEiaSR?p=preview

```
<input type="text" 
       [ngModel]="text"                      //<<<###changed [(ngModel)]="text" to [ngModel]="text"
       (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)"> 

private textChanged(event) {        
    console.log('changed', this.text, event);
    this.text=event;                          //<<<###added 
}
```

Comment: thank you, I marked your answer useful but it seems it won't show yet.

Comment: One tick mark is there. You just need to click it and it will apper in green color.

Comment: @Irtaza click on 'grey check' on the left side of this answer (below points)

Comment: doesnt this breaks two way data binding?

Answer (score 17):

all you need to do is to put
(ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)"
to the left of [(ngModel)] element in the html tag, like:

```
<input (whatever...) (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="text">
```

This way, inside textChanged(event), the element you are binding to still has the previous value, while event is the new one

If you type

```
<input (whatever...) [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)">
```

The event will be called with new value only. However:

```
<input (whatever...) (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)">   -
```

Will get you both events with previous and current value

Comment: This is the correct answer. I did not know that the order of the (ngModelChange) and the [(ngModel)] inside the element is important. Thank you

Comment: Yes this is the correct workaround for the Angular bug!!

In the Angular Doco, under ngModel it says:
"Event emitter for producing the ngModelChange event after the view model updates."
NOTE the "after the view model updates"
So that would make it a Angular bug, because it is NOT deterministic!!

Comment: If you need both on and new values then don't use the (ngModelChange)="eventHandlerMethod($event)", use the (change)="eventHandlerMethod($event)"

Answer (score 3):

```
<input (ngModelChange)="preTextChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="postTestChanged($event)">
```

In this way you can know the previous value and the next value

Comment: This behavior was so strange to me. Why would the attribute position for a tag make any difference? They should be named separate. Thank you for clearing this for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getters and setters to retain older values. E.g.

HTML

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text" (ngModelChange)="textChanged($event)">
```

TypeScript:

```
private _text: string = "";
private _oldText: string = "";
get text(): string{
    return this._text;
}
set text(value: string) {
    this._oldText = this._text;
    this._text = value;
}
```

Source: https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-getters-setters/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<input
   [(ngModel)]="actionInputValue"
   (keydown)="prevValue = actionInputValue"
   (keyup)="doSomething()"
/>
```

Now in component `ts` file you can console and check the values.

```
doSomething() {
  console.log(this.prevValue, this.actionInputValue);
}
```

The idea is that `keydown` event occurs before the `ngModel` is updated.